# Best way to use Offline storage for images in React Native

Tags: react-native, offline-storage

I'm stuck for making my react native app offline for storing the images.
what is the best way to use, shall i go with AsyncStorage, Real m, CouchDB or WatermelonDB.
Actually i am new to React Native, so i want to use the best solution.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

By the common ways. There are no databases actually store `media`. They actually save media files in physic / cloud servers and store only access url in database.

So, to achieve your technical goal. You can use [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) to interact with your media files. And save their **url** into your database like `Realm, PouchDB`, `AsyncStorage`.

I think `AsyncStorage` is simple to setup and suitable for save media url.